# How can I re-start to read a list if condition inside it is true?

Tags: python, list

```
import random
i=0
list=[]
while i<10:
    random_i=random.randrange(0, 1000)
    i=i+1
    list.append(random_i)

for i in list:
    if i%2 ==0:
        list.remove(i)

print(list)
```

My question is if there is any way to re-start to read the list when "i" will an even number.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: in Python it is better to create new list to keep odd numbers instead of removing even numbers.

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name since `list` is a built-in function in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. Here is my approach:

```
import random

random.seed(73214)

i=0
my_list=[]

while i<10:
    random_i=random.randrange(0, 1000)
    my_list.append(random_i)
    i += 1

len_list = len(my_list)
i = 0

while i < len_list:
    print(my_list[i])
    if my_list[i] % 2 == 0:
        my_list.pop(i)
        len_list = len(my_list)
        i = 0
    else:
        i += 1

print(my_list)
```